# F-test can be used to analyse discrete data?

Tags: self-study, statistical-significance, anova, discrete-data, percentage

I have 2 sets of discrete data. My objective is to compare 2 different process which is manual strip and auto-layering machine. But my data are in percentage of scrap. Can I use F-test to analyse the data?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to CV!  Could you explain in what sense you consider these data to be discrete?  Have you viewed a scatterplot of these data?

Comment: Because it is a countable data. But I want to compare 2 process here.

Comment: I would urge you to rethink this.  There is no reason to analyze these data as discrete.  Regardless, could you be more specific about what you mean by "analyze"?  What is it you want to learn or test about these data?